# Analytic function on unit disk with $|f(z)|\le1$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be analytic function on $D=\{z\in\mathbb C:\left\lvert z\right\rvert<1\}$. Assume that for each $z\in D$, $\left\lvert f(z)\right\rvert \le1$.
>
> Then, which of the following is not the possible value of $(e^f)''(0)$:
>
> (a) $2$
>
> (b) $6$
>
> (c) $\frac{7}{9} e^\frac{1}{9}$
>
> (d) $\sqrt{2}+i\sqrt{2}$

I have tried the following:

Let $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$ then,

$g''(z)=(f''(z)+(f'(z))^2)e^{f(z)}$

Now, $g''(0)=(f''(0)+(f'(0))^2)e^{f(0)}$

What next to do after this step, or is there any other easier way to solve it?

Comment: On this site, you need to provide your thoughts and attempts along with your question in the post. In this way, you might receive positive and constructive feeback.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: @user1952009, how to use Cauchy Integral formula here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I take a look at Cauchy Integral Formula and then $$(e^{f})''(0)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{e^{f(z)}}{z^3}$$

Taking modulus on both sides we have $$|(e^{f})''(0)| \le \frac{e}{\pi}2\pi=2e$$

Hence (b) cannot be the choice.